# helm loop over a map and use variable file

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a deployment.yaml template

```
  env:
  {{- range .Values.env_map }}
  - name: {{ .name }}
    value: {{ .value }}
  {{ end }}
```

and my file env variable : env/values.dev.yaml

```
env_map:
  - name: toto
    value: {{ .Values.release_name }}-toto-{{ .Values.env }}
```

my values.yaml

```
release_name: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

I want to use .Release.Name and variable inside the same file.

I have got an error when I try :

```
helm template toto . -f env/values.dev.yaml
    Error: failed to parse env/values.dev.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 2: did not find expected key
```

how I can give Release.Name through the env file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [tpl function](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function)

values.yaml

```yaml
env_map:
  - name: toto
    value: "{{ .Release.Name }}-toto-{{ .Release.Name }}"
  - name: momo
    value: "{{ .Release.Name }}-momo-{{ .Release.Name }}"
  - name: nono
    value: "{{ .Release.Name }}-nono-{{ .Release.Name }}"
```

templates/deployment.yaml

```yaml
  env:
  {{- range .Values.env_map }}
  - name: {{ .name }}
    value: {{ tpl .value $ }}
  {{- end }}
```

output

```yaml
  env:
  - name: toto
    value: test-toto-test
  - name: momo
    value: test-momo-test
  - name: nono
    value: test-nono-test
```

Comment: thanks it works, is that I want! I dont't know what is tpl